# concatenate 2 matrices

Tags: c, dynamic, matrix

I have a matrix dynamically allocated and I want to create another one which is the first matrix but with another copy beside. for example,I have the matrix:

```
11
22
```

My new matrix will be:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
```

How can I concatenate them? This is my code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int **create_matrix(int row, int col)
{
    int **matrix = malloc(sizeof (int*)*row);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof (int)*col);
    }
    return matrix;
}

void matrix_input(int **matrix, int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("enter the elements of the matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int **extend_matrix(int **matrix, int row, int col)
{
    int k, j;
    int i;
    int **extend_matrix = malloc(sizeof (int*)*row);
    for (k = 0; k < row + row; k++)
    {
        extend_matrix[k] = malloc(sizeof (int)*col);
    }
    extend_matrix = matrix;
    extend_matrix = (int**) realloc(extend_matrix, (row + row) * sizeof (int*));
    extend_matrix[j] = matrix[j];
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        extend_matrix[k] = matrix[i];
    }
}

void print_matrix(int **matrix, int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void print_extend_matrix(int **extend_matrix, int row, int col)
{
    int k, j;
    for (k = 0; k < row + row; k++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", extend_matrix[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int **matrix;
    int **extend_matrix;
    int row, col;
    printf("enter the number of rows of cols:");
    scanf("%i%i", &row, &col);
    matrix = create_matrix(row, col);
    matrix_input(matrix, row, col);
    print_matrix(matrix, row, col);
    print_extend_matrix(extend_matrix, row, col);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not using veritable matrices, but only an emulation through array of pointers. This is a bad design from the start.

Comment: At a quick glance did you forget to call extend_matrix() in your code? Also you aer not returning anything from extend matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @NPE suggested to you a better way. If you want to allocate memory in extend_matrix()

error in your code (*read comments*)

```
int **extend_matrix = malloc(sizeof (int*)*row);
                                           ^ on row
for (k = 0; k < row + row; k++)            
                    ^ where as loop is for row + row
{
    extend_matrix[k] = malloc(sizeof (int)*col);  // So this cause an error,
                                                  // segment-fault
}
```

second, your concept is wrong to copy memory:

```
 extend_matrix = matrix;
```

at this line you are assigning `matrix` to  `extend_matrix` its wrong. you need loop here to copy each elements from `matrix[][]` to `extend_matrix[][]`. (*but rectify your memory allocation code first*)

Answer (score 2):

I think `extend_matrix()` should just call `create_matrix()` to create a new matrix of double the width, and then use two simple nested loops to populate it.

Comment: This would be the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are looking for :

```
int concat(void * oldM, int row, int col,void& *newM) {
     newM = malloc(sizeof(int)*row*col*2);

     for(int i = 0;i<2;++i)
      for(int j=0;j<2;++j)
         newM[i][j+col] = newM[i][j] = oldM[i][j]; 

    for(int i = 0;i<2;++i)  {
      for(int j=0;j<4;++j) {
        cout<<"\t"<<newM[i][j];
      }
      cout<<"\n";
   }
}
```