# Concatenate two matrices in C

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to concatenate the same matrix in C, and the only idea that crossed to my mind is addition, but it doesn't work. For example, if I have: `{1,1;2,2}`, my new matrix should be `{1,1,1,1;2,2,2,2}`. I want to double the number of rows. I Googled, but I didn't find anything.

Here is my code:

```
 matrix2=realloc(matrix1,sizeof(int*)*(row));
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<row;i++){
   for(j=0;j<col;j++){    
    matrix2[i][j]=matrix1[i][j]+matrix1[i][j];
   }
 }
```

Comment: You mean you have a single matrix and you want to... double the size of the rows?

Comment: exactly...the new matrix I allocated with realloc

Comment: in this code I can notice this `matrix2[i][j]=matrix1[i][j]+matrix1;` is problematic?

Comment: Is this also you [concatenate 2 matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197135/concatenate-2-matrices/15197662#15197662) ? If not you! get an idea from here :)

Comment: No,I just tried. I don't know how to put them together. just an hint I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the psuedocode I provide below. Note that for any C before C99, you cannot instantiate arrays with `int matrix[2*W][H]` (if W and H are not `#define`s)

```
Given matrix1 and matrix 2 of equal W,H
make matrix3 of 2*W,H
for h to H
    for i to W
        matrix3[h][i] = matrix1[h][i]
        matrix3[h][i+W] = matrix2[h][i]
```

Making the matrix will require 1 malloc per row, plus 1 malloc to store the array of row pointers.

Note how you will need 2 assignments in the loop instead of the one you had before. This is because you are setting in two places.

Comment: Your first sentence needs clarification.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks. Is that better?

Comment: actually no. You *can* declare a 2d array if `W` and `H` are compile time constants. See here http://ideone.com/byYkYX

Comment: Instead of being fairly certain, I suggest you check first. http://ideone.com/2XaH4d  
Macros are handled by the pre-processor. It is simple text substitution. The result is an arithmetical expression that can be evaluted to a compile time constant.

Comment: @StoryTeller Very well, I changed the wording.

Comment: I'd also add that in `C99` you *have* variable length arrays, and then `W` and `H` don't have to be known at compile time. But it's good enough.

Comment: I know it seems like I'm just picking on you, but you must bear in mind that Q&As on SO should contain generally applicable and correct information. That's something to always remeber when we answer questions here.

Comment: I will take a look at that later and update the answer when I have time for researching.

Answer (score 1):

You sound like you have a background with higher level languages like matlab.  In C the plus operator does not concatenate matrices.  This will add the values in the matrices and store the new value into the new matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are copying the input matrix into a new matrix twice

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){for(int j = 0; j < n;j++)
{  mat2[i][j] = mat[i][j];}}

for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){for(int j = n; j < (2*n) ; j++){   mat2[i][j] = mat[i][j-n];}}